# rxjs takeUntil do not execute finalize

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, pipe, finalize

I have the following countdown:

```
userClick=new Subject()

resetCountdown(){this.userClick.next()}

setCountDown() {
    let counter = 5;
    let tick = 1000;
    this.countDown = timer(0, tick)
    .pipe(
      take(counter),
      map(() => --counter),
      takeUntil(this.userClick),
      finalize(() => {
        if (this.currentQuestionNumber < this.questionsToAsk)
          this.showNextQuestion();
        else {
          this.endQuiz();
        }

      })
    );
}
```

When `takeUntil(this.userClick)` occurs, I do not want `finalize` to be executed. Is there any possibility to achieve that? I only want `finalize` to be executed when the countdown has reached `0` and was not interrupted before by `takeUntil`

Comment: Try use flat arrow: takeUntil(()=>this.userClick) -I don't know if work, it's only a suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tap` to check if the value has reached your target and execute sideeffects.
Something like

```js
function setCountDown() {
    let counter = 5;
    let tick = 1000;
    this.countDown = timer(0, tick)
      .pipe(
        take(counter + 1),
        map(value => counter - value),
        tap(value => {
          if (value === 0) {
            console.log('OUT OF TIME');
          }
        }),
        takeUntil(userClick)
      )
}
```

See this [example](https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/0bae1cf4f1efa4db0ad0ae0d57d025d6)

Comment: Thanks, one thing: the solution counts up, but I want it to count down?